# How to display database data after selecting the item from spinner?

Tags: android

I want to display person details from reg_farmer table.. If i select an item from the spinner, i want to display the corresponding data matches with that item from the database.

Here is my android MainActivity.class file..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declaring an Spinner
private Spinner spinner,spinner2;

//An ArrayList for Spinner Items
private ArrayList<String> states;
private ArrayList<String> district;

//JSON Array
private JSONArray States;
private JSONArray District;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing the ArrayList
    states = new ArrayList<String>();
    district = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Initializing Spinner
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String sid="";
            try {
                //Getting object of given index
                JSONObject json = States.getJSONObject(position);

                //Fetching id from that object
                sid = json.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getDistrict(sid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Nothing Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Dname="";
            try {
                //Getting object of given index
                JSONObject json = District.getJSONObject(position);

                //Fetching name from that object
                Dname = json.getString("dname");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Dname,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    //This method will fetch the States data from the URL
   getStates();

}

private void getStates(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.DATA_State,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        States = j.getJSONArray("States");


                        for(int i=0;i< States.length();i++){
                            try {
                                //Getting json object
                                JSONObject state = States.getJSONObject(i);

                                //Adding the name of the state to array list
                                MainActivity.this.states.add(state.getString("name"));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
                        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, states));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getDistrict(final String sid){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest dRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.DATA_District,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + response + "]");
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        boolean error = j.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            District = j.getJSONArray("District");

                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, District.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            district.removeAll(district);
                            for (int i = 0; i < District.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    //Getting json object
                                    JSONObject dist = District.getJSONObject(i);
                                    //Adding the name of the district to array list
                                    MainActivity.this.district.add(dist.getString("dname"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
                            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, district));
                        }else {

                            String errorMsg = j.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("state_id", sid);
            return params;
        }

    };

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(dRequest);
}
}
```

Here is my Config.java file.. In this file i give the url for fetching spinner items..

```
public class Config {
//JSON URL
public static final String DATA_State = "http://10.0.3.2/cof/state.php";
public static final String DATA_District = "http://10.0.3.2/cof/district.php";

}
```

I want to display the details like this.. I want to view code,name and mobile number of the person when i choose the district and state from the spinner
[image: I want to display the details like this.. I want to view code,name and mobile number of the person when i choose the district and state from the spinner]

Comment: do you have any webservice that returns these data when you pass corresponding state and district ?

Comment: no... i wrote php code

Comment: that code is returning the data when you pass corresponding state and district ?

Comment: You must parse json to array list. Then use array list load data to spinner

Comment: @janki .. yes..  $sql = "SELECT * FROM reg_farmer WHERE dist_name='".$dist_name."'";

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to communicate with a local database. Getting data from an eternal database requires 3 steps.

1. Creating your database - it can be local using services like wamp or it can be present on actual server.
2. Creating webservice - In this step you need to create a Webservice which interacts with your database and responds to your android code. It includes making of config. php file which stores your server & database information, then you have your actual anyname.php file which include config.php file, the code to get the data from database and to respond back to android app.
3. Calling webservice from android -  In this step you actually call the webservice from your code to retrieve data from it.

Now as we can see from your provided code. You might have completed most or all of these steps. According to me you have your database ready. You have shown the config folder with two php files which shows that you have your php files ready.

Now to debug, first try to open the links in your browser and see if you get any result. If you get the information correctly then it means that you have placed the files correctly. Now try to print the result of volley in logcat to see if you have the data in your app. If everything works fine then you only have to handle spinner listener. If any of these steps fail, tell us about it.

Comment: i donno how to handle spinner listener.... now my app only showing 2 spinners.. if i select state the corresponding district will shown in next spinner... i want to display person details according to the spinners selection. can yu help me??

Answer (score 0):

First you have to retrieve all the data then adding them to an array list so you could get the info again,

You can look at that example it does what you want exactly ,

```
 private void retrieveJSON() {


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URLstring,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("strrrrr", ">>" + response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        goodModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {



                                PMenus playerModel = new PMenus();

                                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);



                                playerModel.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                                playerModel.setCountry(dataobj.getString("country"));
                                playerModel.setCity(dataobj.getString("city"));
                                playerModel.setImgURL(dataobj.getString("imgURL"));



                                goodModelArrayList.add(playerModel);



                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < goodModelArrayList.size(); i++){
                                names.add(goodModelArrayList.get(i).getName().toString());
                            }

                            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddPatient.this, simple_spinner_item, names);
                            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                            PmSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    // request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

Now after adding the data into an array you can use this method

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() ;
            String city = goodModelArrayList.get(position).getCity().toString() ;
            String country = goodModelArrayList.get(position).getCountry().toString() ;



            testnotes.setText(item);
            testno.setText(city);
            testprice.setText(country);


        }
```

and ofcourse don't forget to add this line in you onCreate

```
        goodModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and define it like that

```
    private ArrayList<PMenus> goodModelArrayList;
```